# 404 and 500 errors deploying node js on GC appengine

Tags: node.js, google-cloud-platform, google-app-engine, deployment

I am trying to deploy a simple node js app (via Google Cloud app engine) with a static html front end, found [here](https://github.com/evangoesonline/seinfeld-quotes-api/tree/main). It works fine locally, and previously I was able to deploy the back end api and the front end without issue to appengine. However, as a result of trying to deploy both successfully (and related tinkering), I now have errors on both front end (404) and back end (500). I have looked through the logs and spent 12+ hours trying to figure this out (including poring over the logs). I realize there are similar questions, however after spending a few hours reviewing them, I am at a loss and coming to the group with my tail between my legs for an assist.
I believe I have narrowed down the issue to something in app.yaml and package.json. Sorry if the current version of app.yaml (pasted below) is a mess, I have tried everything with this file to try and resolve. Seems to be around the URL handlers but I am truly at a loss. Where before I could successfully have front end or back end running, now I am unsure what the issue is.
app.yaml:

```
runtime: nodejs20
env: standard
instance_class: F1
handlers:
  - url: /api/quotes
    script: auto
  - url: /(.*)
    static_files: public/\1
    upload: public/.*
  - url: /(.*\.js)
    static_files: ../public/\1
    upload: /public/(.*\.js)
  - url: /(.*\.css)
    static_files: /public/\1
    upload: /public/(.*\.css)
  - url: /.*
    script: auto
  - url: .*
    script: auto
env_variables:
  MONGODB_URI: >-
    mongodb+srv://user:password@cluster0.effzkgn.mongodb.net/?retryWrites=true&w=majority
automatic_scaling:
  min_idle_instances: automatic
  max_idle_instances: automatic
  min_pending_latency: automatic
  max_pending_latency: automatic
service_account: app-proj-name-here@appspot.gserviceaccount.com
```

Note in the above I have replaced the mongodb password for security reasons but the actual file has it and works fine.

Below is the textPayload field from the error in the logs

```
from Error: Cannot find module '/workspace/server.js'
    at Module._resolveFilename (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:1048:15)
    at Module._load (node:internal/modules/cjs/loader:901:27)
    at Function.executeUserEntryPoint [as runMain] (node:internal/modules/run_main:83:12)
    at node:internal/main/run_main_module:23:47 {
```

I know this is a simple novice error but any help would be appreciated as I have exhausted every option I can think of. Thank you!

**Edit:** I was able to fix the backend and the api/quotes route is returning data as expected now! However, I am still getting a 404 for front end (/), but I am still perplexed by how to modify the app.yaml file to fix (assuming the issue lies here).

Latest logs for front end 404:

> logMessage: "Static file referenced by handler not found: public/"

Front end error in browser (console also returns 404):

> Error: Not Found
> The requested URL / was not found on this server.
> Based on the logs and what I see in browser, I am need to change the URL handler in app.yaml for homepage but am still a bit unsure of *exactly* how the upload and static_files fields work. Obviously the handler set up for the "/" route is off but I have been going in circles trying to modify.

Answer (score 2):

1. When you define URL handlers, you should start with the most restrictive patterns and then go down to less restrictive ones. From your current `app.yaml`, `- url: /(.*)` will match all of your files including the ones that end in `.js` or `.css` which means the other handlers you created e.g. `/(.*\.js)` and `/(.*\.css)` won't be triggered. You should put those two above the `- url: /(.*)` handler
2. From your description, does this mean you're deploying 2 different services? If so, it would mean that you need 2 different `app.yaml` in which case which one do you have here in your question? You have `../public/\1` and `public/\1`. Do you have 2 public folders or is it that you're accessing the public folder from different levels of your application?

Comment: Thanks for the tip! The app.yaml file above was the result of just endless messing around with it and I got a bit careless (not reverting breaking changes/those that did not work), and that is why we see the 2 different public folders.